# Using PIP from Docker container (Airflow): Bad interpreter / no such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, pip, path, airflow

I am currently trying to put a Python based application in a Docker container. It works locally on my host machine.

I bound the local directory */Users/MyUser/Git/MyProject* containing my virtual environment (venv) to the Docker container (to */myapp/*) with the `--mount` option.

When running commands that involve PIP using the Airflow *BashOperator*, the virtual environment / PIP is not reachable from the Docker container:

```
show = BashOperator(
        task_id='show',
        cwd=/myapp/,
        bash_command='pwd; ls; python3 --version;'
                     ' $(pwd)/venv/bin/pip --version; $(pwd)/venv/bin/pip list'
    )
```

With two times the same error:

```
/bin/bash: /myapp/venv/bin/pip: /Users/MyUser/Git/MyProject/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Somehow, the host path */Users/MyUser/Git/MyProject* is not correctly mapped to the Docker path */myapp/*.
I get this error everytime when I try to use either PIP, the venv, or the Python on my host machine.

**tl;dr:** Need to use the venv on my host machine in Docker container with Airflow, path problem, get 'bad interpreter' and 'no such file or directory' errors

EDIT: I also made sure via `ls /myapp/` that the files at */Users/MyUser/Git/MyProject* are shown in */myapp*. And the Python version in the Docker container matches the one used by the venv on the host machine.